# Text Overlapping in Styled Component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Here is my CSS

```
const MessageText = styled(TextWithPaddingLeft)`
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  display: -webkit-box;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding-right: 39px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow-y: auto;
```

It seems that in the current CSS styling for the MessageText in my EditMessageModal component, there is an issue where the text is overlapping with other content when there is a larger amount of text. This overlap is causing readability and visual problems.

How can I fix this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a predefined min-width and min-height. I had a similar issue and fixed it by doing it.

Comment: Thanks , It worked when removing  `-webkit-line-clamp: 3`;  and using `max-height`.